# Can you add an image to an internal css stylesheet from one's own files?

Tags: html, css, file, background-image

I have been making some basic html/css and i wanted to add in a background image so i found one in the file explorer and thought it would be suitable so I wrote the code to add it in but it seems to not be working, so, my question is: can one take an image stored on one's own computer and use it in css.

This is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body 
            {
                background-image: ('C:\Users\***\Pictures\Image.png');
            }

            h2
            {
                color : yellowgreen;
            }
        </style>

        <body>
            <h2> This is green </h2>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: open image in browser. Copy Address bar URL and paste there. OR you can copy that image in same directory and use like `background-image: ('Image.png');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you deploy your site on web referencing your computer path so this is not good practice please use path of your project inside your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

body 
            {
                background-image: url('your image path');
            }

your image path should be in browser friendly. Simply drag that image in any of your browser and copy the link from browser address bar and paste it in css i-e:'your image path'